# Maximum coin that can be collected in a grid

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

There is a grid G . 
G(i,j)=-1 implies path blocked.
Otherwise G(i,j) = number of coins at (i,j).

Always start from point start point (0,0) goto end point (n,n) then come back to start point (0,0).  Once coins at any location is collected it can't be collected again. However you can still have a path through that location.

What is the maximum number of coins that can be collected if you can travel in top, bottom, left, right directions?

I know how to get the maximum number of coins when you only have to go from (0,0) to (n,n) using recursion but not able to track which coins I have already collected while traveling from start to end.

Please suggest a good approach or refer to some source.

Answer (score 1):

Task specification doesn't require the path to be shortest nor to avoid repeated visit of field. So if the point `(n,n)` is reachable from point `(0,0)`, the result is effectively sum of all points reachable from them (which can be computed using Flood-fill algorithm); zero otherwise.

Frankly, I suppose you omitted some important constraint in the task specification. Until fixed, it's hard to guess which algorithm is the best solution (for example Dijkstra when looking for shortest path, dynamic programming when moves restricted to right and down etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As your question does not have any restriction on how many steps can be performed. You only need to add up the value of all grids as you can potentially pick up all coins by walking over all grids.